# Number of baseballs used in a major league baseball game?

Tags: baseball, mlb

The title says it all. What is the average number of baseballs used in a 9 inning game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question doesn't have an exact answer but there are many articles which suggest, for a particular (9 innings) game , on avergage [8 to 10 dozen baseballs](http://mashable.com/2015/01/24/sports-balls-nfl-deflate-gate/#HGUkfQdLhqqX) are used.

From [old.post-gazette.com](http://old.post-gazette.com/pg/05142/508138.stm) article (link might be dead, information is taken from a [thread](http://www.spiritstranslation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=833&start=80) citing this source.)

> According to the Pirates' equipment manager, an actual game between the Pittsburgh Pirates and Milwaukee Brewers, used 104 baseballs.

Which is just above 8 dozen balls.

From a [foxsports.com](http://www.foxsports.com/other/story/major-league-baseballs-have-a-short-shelf-life-062912) article according to Twins assistant equipment manager Tim Burke,

> On any given night, teams will go through 100 baseballs or more, which equates to just a few pitches per ball.